# Probability tensor multiplication using pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, statistics, pandas, probability, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking for a good way to store and use conditional probabilities in python.

I'm thinking of using a `pandas` dataframe. If the conditional probabilities of some `X` are `P(X=A|P1=1, P2=1) = 0.2`, `P(X=B|P1=2, P2=1) = 0.9` etc., I would use the dataframe

```
         A    B
P1 P2          
1  1   0.2  0.8
   2   0.5  0.5
2  1   0.9  0.1
   2   0.9  0.1
```

and given the marginal probabilities of `P1` and `P2` as Series

```
1    0.4
2    0.6
Name: P1

1    0.7
2    0.3
Name: P2
```

I would like to obtain the Series of marginal probabilities of `X`, i.e. the series

```
A    0.602
B    0.398
Name: X
```

I can get what I want by

```
X = sum(
    sum(
        X.xs(i, level="P1")*P1[i]
        for i in P1.index
        ).xs(j)*P2[j]
    for j in P2.index
    )
X.name="X"
```

but this is not easily generalizable to more dependencies, the asymmetry between the first `xs` with `level` and the second one without looks weird and as usual when working with `pandas` I'm very sure that there is a better solution using it's tricks and methods.

Is `pandas` a good tool for this, should I represent my data in another way, and what is the best way to do this calculation, which is essentially an indexed tensor product, in `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to vectorize is access the values in Series P1 and P2 by indexing with an array of labels.

```
In [20]: df = X.reset_index()

In [21]: mP1 = P1[df.P1].values

In [22]: mP2 = P2[df.P2].values

In [23]: mP1
Out[23]: array([ 0.4,  0.4,  0.6,  0.6])

In [24]: mP2
Out[24]: array([ 0.7,  0.3,  0.7,  0.3])

In [25]: mp = mP1 * mP2

In [26]: mp
Out[26]: array([ 0.28,  0.12,  0.42,  0.18])

In [27]: X.mul(mp, axis=0)
Out[27]: 
       A      B
P1 P2              
1  1   0.056  0.224
   2   0.060  0.060
2  1   0.378  0.042
   2   0.162  0.018

In [28]: X.mul(mp, axis=0).sum()
Out[28]: 
A    0.656
B    0.344

In [29]: sum(
    sum(
    X.xs(i, level="P1")*P1[i]
    for i in P1.index
    ).xs(j)*P2[j]
    for j in P2.index
    )
Out[29]: 
A    0.656
B    0.344
```

(Alternately, access the values of a MultiIndex 
without resetting the index as follows.)

```
In [38]: P1[X.index.get_level_values("P1")].values
Out[38]: array([ 0.4,  0.4,  0.6,  0.6])
```